# messageReactionAdd event is only firing when the bot reacts to a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a messageReactionAdd event and it is only firing when the bot reacts to a message.

Here is my event

```js
module.exports = async function messageReactionAdd(reaction, user) {
  console.log("fire");
};
```

And here is the event loader

```js
 async loadEvents(eventsDir) {
  const eventFiles = await readdir(eventsDir);

  eventFiles.forEach((file, i) => {
    const eventName = file.split(".")[0];
    const event = require(path.join(eventsDir, file));
    this.on(eventName, event.bind(null, this));

    console.log(`Loaded event: ${eventName}`);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the ClientOptions

```js
partials: ["GUILD_MEMBER", "USER", "MESSAGE", "REACTION", "CHANNEL"]
```

Comment: is it still works on old messages after restart?